# How can I make an organized file into dictionary in python3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, dictionary, set

I'm trying to make this file:

```
c;f
b;d
a;c
c;e
d;g
a;b
e;d
f;g
f;d
```

Into a dict like this:

```
{'e': {'d'}, 'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'b': {'d'}, 'c': {'f', 'e'}, 'f': {'g', 'd'}}.
```

The code I'm using now is like below:

```
def read_file(file : open) -> {str:{str}}:
f = file.read().rstrip('\n').split()
answer = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.split(';')
    answer[k] = v
return answer
```

But it gives me `{'f': 'g', 'a': 'c', 'b': 'd', 'e': 'd', 'c': 'e', 'd': 'g'}`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries overwrite the previous key, Use a [defaultdict here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
>>> import collections 
>>> answer = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> for line in f: 
...     k, v = line.split(";")
...     answer[k].add(v)
... 
>>> answer
defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'b': {'d'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'e': {'d'}, 'a': {'c', 'b'}, 'c': {'f', 'e'}})
```

If you prefer the traditional approach, then you can add a `if` condition

```
>>> answer = {}
>>> for line in f:
...     k,v = line.split(";")
...     if k in answer:
...         answer[k].add(v)
...     else:
...         answer[k] = {v}
... 
>>> answer
{'b': {'d'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'e': {'d'}, 'a': {'c', 'b'}, 'c': {'f', 'e'}}
```

Comment: But I still have a question: the dict class is hashable, so why we don't just use default dict instead for all the coding works? Looks like default dict is more flexiable.

Comment: @ProgrammingDonkey The default dict is more flexible in a few use cases, the normal dict in others. Whenever we don't need to have a default value, or throw an error when we don't have that particular key, we cannot use the default dict. Hence there is a strong reason that dict  is given more prominence over default dict.